# Equivalent Apex Function for bytes

Tags: apex

I'm trying to convert python code that encode some data into apex and having some issue when the python uses function bytes

In python its

```
header = sha3_256(f"{bytes(str('someinput'), 'utf-8')}".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
print(header)
```

And the apex translation is

```
String header = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA3-256', Blob.valueOf('someinput')));
System.debug(header);
```

but the output is not the same mainly because the function "bytes" in python which I don't know if and what is the equivalent in SF.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

**This answer was a try but does not solve the question , please read notes below.**

I would say that you don't apply the functions in the same order :

- In python you apply sha() to the bytes array for the string
- In Apex you transform to bytes the result of sha function()

It can't be the same.

I would have *translated* python to :

```
String header = (
   Crypto.generateDigest(
      'SHA3-256', 
      Blob.valueOf(
          EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Blob.valueOf('some_data'))
      )
    )
).toString();
System.debug(header);
```

Note : it returns "not a valid utf8 string"

Comment: I don't know python but when I try to run your code I get a *invalid syntax* message

Comment: Question is how I can do the same in Apex? Without the bytes() function in python it does give me the same result, but I don't think there is equivalent function in apex.

Comment: Can you please confirm if your python code works, or correct it ? when I run it in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php I have an error and I'm not able to correct it myself

Comment: It works. Seems need to use python 3+, while the tool you use is older. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: from hashlib import sha3_256
header = sha3_256(f"{bytes(str('someinput'), 'utf-8')}".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
print(header)

Comment: I've been searching and tried many things but the Bytes type does not exist in Apex. As said here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zo1IAA the closest type will be a String. Maybe try to have a look at the suggested library https://code.google.com/archive/p/apex-lang/ ?